# How can I installed Remix IDE for offline use?

Tags: windows-10, blockchain, solidity, desktop-application, remix

How can I installed remix IDE on desktop for offline use because sometimes I don't have internet. I'm not be able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you can download the desktop version

https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases/

this is the guide:

https://medium.com/remix-ide/getting-started-with-remix-desktop-5f6380568d12